# Conditional LOOKUPVALUE() in Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

Hi, wasn't sure how to show the data so I pasted above.

Anyways, consider Table 1 and Table 2. What I want to do, is look up the value for Business in Table 2 based on the Job ID. As you can see, the Job ID in table 1 is distinct/unique but the Job ID in Table 2 isn't (for Job ID 123 and 125).

What I want to do is look up the value of Business in Table 2 and bring it over to Table 1 based on the latest date.

For example, Job ID 123 should be "Aero" in Table 1, because the Date of 11/12/2010 is later than 11/11/2010 in Table 2. The same would apply to Job ID 125. But Job 124 will stay as Mechanical as that is a unique Job ID.

Hope that makes sense. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can see I am looking at an excelsheet and not at powerbi. If you need help, I would advise you to show us what you have build so far. The fun part is, if you would use powerbi, you do not have to do anything in the User interface as it is supported. If the question is to create a different table, it becomes a different matter. This is why we need to understand what you ahve been doing so far.

Comment: I just did this as a snippet to show the data but it is being done in Power BI. So I have a 2 tables. Table 1 and Table 2.

I tried to do 
= LOOKUPVALUE( 'Table 2'[Business], 'Table2'[Job ID], 'Table 1'[Job ID]). But this does not work as PowerBI doesn't know which row to take in the business column as there are multiple Job ID's in Table 2.

Comment: Please paste your sample data as copiable text along with a table showing expected results. Thanks

Comment: The underlying principle of Power BI is totally different than Excel. Have a look on Data Modeling. Then the first comment above becomes more clear. Basically, you need to create a measure to do what xlookup in Excel does for you: to choose the desired date from the multiple lines with the same ID. The measure depends on how your data model looks like.